# Generating a list of URLs with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to generate a list of URLs with Selenium.
I would like the user to navigate through the instrumented browser and finally create a list of URL that he visited.

I found that the property "current_url" could help to do that but I didn't find a way to know that the user clicked on a link.

```
In [117]: from selenium import webdriver

In [118]: browser = webdriver.Chrome()

In [119]: browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

--> here, I click on the "Questions" link.

In [120]: browser.current_url

Out[120]: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions'

--> here, I click on the "Jobs" link.

In [121]: browser.current_url

Out[121]: 'http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab'
```

Any hint appreciated !

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really an official way to monitor what a user is doing in Selenium. The only thing you can really do is start the driver, then run a loop that is constantly checking the `driver.current_url`. However, I don't know what the best way to exit this loop is since i don't know what your usage is. Maybe try something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver


urls = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

current = 'http://www.google.com'
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
while True:
    if driver.current_url != current:
        current = driver.current_url

        # if you want to capture every URL, including duplicates:
        urls.append(current)

        # or if you only want to capture unique URLs:
        if current not in urls:
            urls.append(current)
```

If you don't have any idea on how to end this loop, i'd suggest either the user navigating to a url that will break the loop, such as `http://www.endseleniumcheck.com` and add it into the code as such:

```
from selenium import webdriver


urls = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

current = 'http://www.google.com'
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
while True:
    if driver.current_url == 'http://www.endseleniumcheck.com':
        break

    if driver.current_url != current:
        current = driver.current_url

        # if you want to capture every URL, including duplicates:
        urls.append(current)

        # or if you only want to capture unique URLs:
        if current not in urls:
            urls.append(current)
```

Or, if you want to get crafty, you can terminate the loop when the user exit's the browser. You can do this by monitoring the Process ID with the `psutil` library (`pip install psutil`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import psutil


urls = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
pid = driver.binary.process.pid

current = 'http://www.google.com'
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
while True:
    if pid not in psutil.pids():
        break

    if driver.current_url != current:
        current = driver.current_url

        # if you want to capture every URL, including duplicates:
        urls.append(current)

        # or if you only want to capture unique URLs:
        if current not in urls:
            urls.append(current)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It will do. Personally, I finally used a try/catch structure in order to handle the browser exit (throwing an exception). It's not clean but good enough for what I'm trying to do.